# How can we make tab menus dynamically. How can we show it in wordpress theme

Tags: tabs

menu addition in wordpress ok. But I couldn't figure out how to add Tabs Menu in Wordpress. I want to do it without page refresh (nav-tabs class). For example 3 tabs just below the slider in the link. (https://www.deneme.website/)But I want it to be dynamic menu. The relevant codes are as follows:

Edit:
Thank you for your interest.

my English is bad. sorry

1- As you know, the menu in wordpress is made with the newwalker class.

```
require_once (get_template_directory().'/classes/class-wp-bootstrap-navwalker.php');
    register_nav_menus(array(
        'menu-1' => __( 'Header Menu' ),
        'menu-2' => __( 'Footer Menu' ),
        'menu-3' => __( 'Nav-Tabs Menu' )
    ) );
```

and:

```
    <?php 
wp_nav_menu(array(
  'theme_location'      => 'menu-1',
  'depth'               => 2,
  'container'           => 'div',
  'container_class'     => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
  'container_id'        => 'navbarResponsive',
  'menu_class'          => 'navbar-nav ml-auto mr-auto active',
  'fallback_cb'         => 'WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker::fallback',
  'walker'              => new WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker()
));
?>
```

ok up to here

2- How to create tab menu with Bootstrap nav-tabs class. Before the page is refreshed, the specified number of content previews should be shown as you click on the menu elements consisting of categories.

3- 'menu-3' => __( 'Nav-Tabs Menu' ) - I'm trying to create the menu on the line.

4- How can I dynamically adapt the menu structure in the following link to wordpress. How should I match the ids? I don't want it to open a new page when I click on the menu items I created from the categories.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/

```
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs mt-3 mb-2" id="myTab" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Genel</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Teknoloji</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#contact" role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false">Web Tasarım</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">  
<div class="row">
    <?php $query = new WP_Query('showposts=3&category_name=genel'); ?>
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 mb-4 portfolio-item">
       <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="text-muted">
          <div class="card-img img-m zoom">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class=""><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
            <p class="card-text">
              <?php
              $content = get_the_content();
              $content = strip_tags($content);
              echo substr($content,0,175);
              ?>
            </p>
          </div>
          <span>Daha Fazla Oku</span></a>
      </div>
    <?php endwhile; else : ?>
    <p><?php esc_html_e( 'Üzgünüz.. Aradığınız içerik bulunamadı. Diğer sayfaları ziyaret etmenizi tavsiye ederiz.' ); ?></p>
  <?php endif; ?>
</div>
</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">
<div class="row">
    <?php $query = new WP_Query('showposts=3&category_name=teknoloji'); ?>
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 mb-4 portfolio-item">
       <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="text-muted">
          <div class="card-img img-m zoom">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class=""><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
            <p class="card-text">
              <?php
              $content = get_the_content();
              $content = strip_tags($content);
              echo substr($content,0,175);
              ?>
            </p>
          </div>
          <span>Daha Fazla Oku</span></a>
      </div>
    <?php endwhile; else : ?>
    <p><?php esc_html_e( 'Üzgünüz.. Aradığınız içerik bulunamadı. Diğer sayfaları ziyaret etmenizi tavsiye ederiz.' ); ?></p>
  <?php endif; ?>
</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">
    <div class="row">
    <?php $query = new WP_Query('showposts=3&category_name=web-tasarim'); ?>
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 mb-4 portfolio-item">
      <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="text-muted">
          <div class="card-img img-m zoom">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class=""><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
            <p class="card-text">
              <?php
              $content = get_the_content();
              $content = strip_tags($content);
              echo substr($content,0,175);
              ?>
            </p>
          </div>
        <span>Daha Fazla Oku</span></a>
      </div>
    <?php endwhile; else : ?>
    <p><?php esc_html_e( 'Üzgünüz.. Aradığınız içerik bulunamadı. Diğer sayfaları ziyaret etmenizi tavsiye ederiz.' ); ?></p>
  <?php endif; ?>
</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Based on the current description, it's not clear what the question is - at a glance, the code appears to be creating markup for posts within `<div class="tab-pane">`s. That seems like it should fulfill the "dynamic tabs" mentioned? Also, you've capitalized "Tabs Menu" - this is not a core WordPress feature. Are you talking about a specific tab implementation which we should be aware of? Aside: [using `query_posts()` is generally a bad idea](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts).

Comment: I elaborated the question.  can you look again

Comment: I want to create dynamic nav-tab menu on home page. show certain content without refreshing the page